# Windows 7 made 2 hour shift for Daylight Savings Time

Tags: windows-7, time

My win7-64 ultimate has set the clock ahead 2 hours. It appears to have done it in increments of 1 hour, with the second 1 hour shift made sometime today. The first, correct, shift for Daylight Savings was sunday morning. In the clock settings it says Mountain Time UTC-7, but the official time should be Mountain Time UTC-6.

Update for Windows 7 (KB979306) IS installed.

Microsoft appears to be able to turn even setting the clock into a hairball. I need the clock rock solid since I use the computer to record TV programs.

Comment: Do you sync to an external time source? And have you verified that your time-zone is set correctly?

Comment: -- time zone is correct. Was syncing to windows.com, just changed it to nist.gov, perhaps this will help. I am not the only one with this problem.

Comment: -- not only this 2 hour problem, the time was off by about 3 min, so much for syncing. This has always worked for me on earlier systems.

Comment: -- shifting the time 2 hours has nothing to do with my time zone anyway.

Comment: Set your time server to pool.ntp.org -- nist.gov is horribly overloaded (so is Microsoft).